# xcode gamcecenter no player' score displayed

Tags: xcode, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

the following code is used to get current player' score from GameCenter but it does not show any submitted score:

```
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
        let gkScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "myID")
        
        gkScore.value = score
        GKScore.reportScores([gkScore], withCompletionHandler: ( { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                println("Score reported: \(gkScore.value)")
            }
        }
```

Every time app is running error with localizedDescription is displayed but not real score is displayed / reported:

> Error: The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid.
>
> Score reported: 0

Any idea how to fix this while testing app on device?

Thanks for any feedback.

Regards

simoasis

Comment: Have you defined the leaderboard in iTunes Connect? What is the value of `score`?

Comment: Yes, Leaderboard is defined in iTunes Connect (Score format type is set to Integer) and saving highscore to GameCenter by using GKScore.reportScores works fine.

score is set to 'var score = Int64()'

It is not possible to get current highscore out of GameCenter

Comment: fixed it with 
'let leaderBoardRequest = GKLeaderboard()
            leaderBoardRequest.identifier = "myID"
                    let localPlayerScore = leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore
                    println("current Highscore: \(localPlayerScore.value)")'

and loading highscore